# IOException when running Android projects in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ioexception

Every time I try to run an Android project from Eclipse with the Android plugin (Run -> Run), the emulator starts up just fine, but the upload fails, and the Console puts out this error message:

```
[2010-06-17 08:17:55 - HelloAndroid] Failed to upload HelloAndroid.apk on device 'emulator-5554'
[2010-06-17 08:17:55 - HelloAndroid] java.io.IOException: Unable to upload file: Local file doesn't exist.
[2010-06-17 08:17:55 - HelloAndroid] Launch canceled!
```

It seems as though the apk compilation is failing, but there are no other errors in the Console at all except for a lone warning about the project not specifying an API Level requirement:

```
[2010-06-17 08:17:55 - HelloAndroid] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
[2010-06-17 08:17:55 - HelloAndroid] Device API version is 8 (Android 2.2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your manifest file specifies the sdk:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>
```

Comment: Where do I put that line? Directly under the root `<manifest>` tag, under the `<application>` tag, or under the `<activity>` tag?

Comment: anywhere inside the <manifest> tag, but not inside <application>

Comment: I put it directly under the `<application>` tag, and though the console prints no error messages, the program doesn't show on the emulator at all.

EDIT: Oh, just saw that comment. I'll try again.

EDIT2: OK, it still doesn't work.

Comment: For some reason, when I pressed the menu key on the emulator, the program popped up.  I'll have to remember that.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the APK file has not been generated. Try to see if there are compiling errors. If not, try to compile the project by yourself. You can read these interesting articles:

- [How to build Android application package (.apk) from the command line using the SDK tools + continuously integrated using CruiseControl](http://asantoso.wordpress.com/2009/09/15/how-to-build-android-application-package-apk-from-the-command-line-using-the-sdk-tools-continuously-integrated-using-cruisecontrol/)
- [Developing Android without Eclipse or Ant](http://benlynn.blogspot.com/2009/01/developing-android-without-eclipse-or.html)

Comment: There's nothing in the bottom pane labeled "Console", would I see a pop-up error message or would it be in some other place if there was a compilation error?